# Convert text into css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to convert a text into css.
For example in my javascript code . I am getting a value like

```
var text1= <p style='color:red'>sales headline</p>;
```

which i want set in the text div with the style and i am doing like

```
   $("#divVar").text(text1);
```

But it is setting the whole value as 
 `<p style='color:red'>sales headline</p>`

but i want the text *Sales headline* with red color.

Any idea what i am doing wrong here or it can be fixed?

Comment: you are missing quotes in ==> `var text1= "<p style='color:red'>sales headline</p>";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want innerHTML attribute, if you are using jQuery as it appears you might be, then you want to use [html method](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$("#divVar").html(text1);
```

Comment: so does it mean it will override all the css which i have defined in style.css? because i have set font properties e.g size, weight, padding, margin etc which seems to be not working when i tried html() is it replacing my css ?

Comment: Inline style (as it is in this case) will override styles set in stylesheets or parent elements. I think if the style in your CSS is marked as !important it will override the inline styles. So, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you leverage jQuery .css property?

```
$("#divVar").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: actually my problem is i can get any css in the value forexample <p style='color:red'>sales headline</p> or <p style='font-style: normal;'>sales headline</p>. So Css is not consistent

Answer (score 1):

Hi Use html() instead of text()

```
var text1= "<p style='color:red'>sales headline</p>" 
$("#divVar").html(text1);
```

Comment: how does this add any value from the answer already presented by @JsonWinnebeck?

Comment: After posting my reply only i noticed above reply.